# Measured grid labeling in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, grids-graticules

[image][image]Can the grid labels be written along the ends of the grid lines within the data box without Cartography tools and with E / N at the end?

I've been playing with offsets and other options. The only result I got were labels within the box but not along the lines. The chart is not north up.

Editing the labels is not what I'm looking for as there is quite a lot of these charts.

Comment: I would expect so.  Can you include a picture of what you are trying to achieve, and more details about the attempt that got you the closest to what you want, please?

Comment: The closest I got was MGRS grid with different settings.

Comment: How can I insert a picture to my added comment? I only managed to edit my question and add a picture there.

Comment: Your question is where any pictures should go but, as a new user I am not sure if you can include more than one. Comments are only intended to be very temporary.

Comment: You can get them inside the frame with negative offset, but can't  otherwise control the placement of grid labels. I believe there may be a little more control in ArcPro.

Comment: Thank you.Not good news as I can't use ArcPro for this project but at least I know that there is no point to spend to much time on it searching for solution in ArcMap.

Comment: @PolyGeo New users should be able to add more than one image - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291740/329733

Comment: Thanks @Midavalo - I’d never been sure about that so it’s good to see where it is in writing.